# implement customized rawcomparator

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

i need to improve my MR jobs, one thing i think about is implement a customized rawComparator, however my key class have lots of fields as string besides some int fields, i not sure how to parse out the string fields out of the byte[],

my key class

```
public GeneralKey {
  private int day;
  private int hour;
  private String type;
  private String name;
  ..
}
```

my customized rawComparator:

```
public class GeneralKeyComparator extends WritableComparator {
    private static final Text.Comparator TEXT_COMPARATOR = new Text.Comparator();

    protected GeneralKeyComparator() {
        super(GeneralKey.class);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
        int day1 = readInt(b1, s1);
        int day2 = readInt(b2, s2);

        int comp = (intDay1 < intDay2) ? -1 : (intDay1 == intDay2) ? 0 : 1;
        if (0 != comp) {
            return comp;
        }

        int hr1 = readInt(b1, s1+4);
        int hr2 = readInt(b2, s2+4);
        comp = (hr1 < hr2) ? -1 : (hr1 == hr2) ? 0 : 1;

            .... how to compare the String fields here???   

        return comp;
    }
```

google around i found people tried this :

```
try {
    int firstL1 = WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b1[s1]) + readInt(b1, s1+8);
    int firstL2 = WritableUtils.decodeVIntSize(b2[s2]) + readVInt(b2, s2+8);
    comp = TEXT_COMPARATOR.compare(b1, s1, firstL1, b2, s2, firstL2);

} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
}
```

but i don't understand how this work and don't think it works in my case, anyone can help? thanks

added readField() and write() methods here:

```
public void readFields(DataInput input) throws IOException {
    intDay = input.readInt();
    hr = input.readInt();
    type = input.readUTF();
    name = input.readUTF();
    ...
    }

@Override
public void write(DataOutput output) throws IOException {
    output.writeInt(intDay);
    output.writeInt(hr);
    output.writeUTF(type);
    output.writeUTF(name);
            ...
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste the `readFields` and `write` methods in GeneralKey? How to compare the GeneralKey depends on how you write the GeneralKey to binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The example you found will not work for you. The data fields in the key for the example are WritableComparables. You have fundamental types (int, String) instead.

As you are using fundamental types, I assume you have implemented Serialization / deserialization methods for your custom Key type.

For your third and fourth data field which are Java Strings, you should be able to use the compareTo method on the String class.

Other option is to use the WritableComparables instead of using fundamental types and use the same technique as you found on google example.